# What impact the default language used for a user have in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Before I start, I do not want to know **how** to change the default language for a user, but rather what **impact** this has for the user.

When we install a customer database, we configure a user to use the default language of 'British English'. One of our customers changed the language to be 'English'. An innocent change you might ponder but one of our stored procedures used the format `dd-MM-yyyy` (why, don't ask - I'd always use `yyyy-MM-dd`) - which parses fine when the user is 'British English'.

My question is, other than the date, what other impact does setting the default language of the user have?

Comment: It will also change the text of error messages, the user interface text. I know there are a few other things that I am not thinking of. The date issue you encountered is exactly why the ANSI compliant yyyy-mm-dd should be the only format used for string literals representing date values.

Comment: Wow, so no other impact at all.  If anyone else does find anything else, please let me know.